# New user with just USAGE previleges was able to drop a table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I logged into MySQL from root user.

Ran the command:-

```
create user new;
```

Then I logged in as user new. Ran the following commands:-

```
use test;
show grants;
```

The Output was:-

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'LOCALHOST'
```

As I understand, the new user does not have the drop table permissions or any permissions for that matter (except USAGE) on this table.

However when I run the following:-

```
DROP TABLE test_table;
```

The query is successful. Could you please explain why is this happening? How do I disable this user from dropping tables and revoke other permissions from this user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html), there is more you need to consider:

> SHOW GRANTS displays only the privileges granted explicitly to the
>   named account. Other privileges might be available to the account, but
>   they are not displayed. For example, if an anonymous account exists,
>   the named account might be able to use its privileges, but SHOW GRANTS
>   will not display them.

Comment: Hi, but then I didn't grant the 'USAGE' permission explicitly either. I haven't assigned any permission at all.

Comment: According to [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html), USAGE is a synonym for 'no privileges'.

Comment: Ummm...ok... when I ran "select * from information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES;" .... there's just one entry in the table corresponding to user 'new' which is:- "'new'@'%'                      | def           | USAGE                   | NO   "

Comment: So,anyways...any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html mentions CREATE USER creates a new row in the mysql.user table and assigns the account no privileges.
What do you get when you run SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER with user new?

Comment: the same... "GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'LOCALHOST'"